# Attempting to write a function that takes a cardinal direction and coords, returns new coordinates

Tags: python

At the moment I'm writing a function that will take a string of north, east, south, and/or west and then a starting location for both an x and y coordinate on a grid. I'm currently trying to figure out how I can pass, for example, something like "NWenS" into the string and have it able to separate each character and interpret that.
Here's what my program looks like so far:

```
def movement(string, x, y):
    for char in string:
        if string == 'N' or string == 'n':
            y += 1
            return (x, y)
        elif string == 'E' or string == 'e':
            x += 1
            return (x, y)
        elif string == 'S' or string == 's':
            y -= 1
            return (x, y)
        elif string == 'W' or string == 'w':
            x -= 1
            return (x, y)
```

As you can see, I have a line that reads `for char in string:`, but that hasn't been doing the job. Anyone know how I can do this? I also need to figure out how to ignore any other character that is not N, E, S, or W.

Comment: `return` ends the function, so you're just processing the first letter.

Comment: Take `return (x, y)` out of the loop, just do it at the end.

Comment: And instead of testing against both upper and lowercase characters, do `string = string.lower()` at the beginning.

Comment: Your code already ignores other characters, why do you think you need to do something special?

Comment: This seems to have a simple, silly mistake. You loop over characters in the string, so you should be comparing to those individual characters—not `string` itself.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Oh shoot. Do you know how I might go about programming this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main problems in your code:

1. your checking `string == "n"` instead of `char == "n"`
2. you are using `return (x, y)` in the for loop.

The first issue causes your checks to fail, this is because in your cause string is "NWenS", so your check is equivalent to `"NWenS" == "n"` which will never be true, so you never add or subtract anything from `x` or `y`. So you need to compare `char == "n"` instead.

The second issue causes the function to return the values `x` and `y` if the condition is True, this will cause the function to stop executing. So you need to add only one `return (x, y)` after the execution of the for loop.

You can also use `.lower()` on *string* in the for loop to reduce the number of comparisons you need to make.

Your code can look something like this:

```py
def movement(string, x, y):
    for char in string.lower():
        # instead of comparing string with n, you need to compare char.
        # since the string is the complete input you provide i.e: "NWenS"
        if char == 'n':
            y += 1
        elif char == 'e':
            x += 1
        elif char == 's':
            y -= 1
        elif char == 'w':
            x -= 1
    # notice that we return the values of x, y after we have completed the
    # calculations for the entire "string".
    return (x, y)
```

so if you use the following input

```py
test_string = "NWenS"
x = 0
y = 0
a, b = movement(test_string, x, y)
print(f"a: {a}\nb: {b}")
```

you would get the following output

```py
a: 0
b: 1
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much for your help! I had ended up fixing both of the main issues that you mentioned, but I had placed the `.lower()` within the loop, so that definitely helped improve its efficiency. However, once I had moved the `return (x, y)` to outside the loop, I hadn't indented properly. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @heth1234 , please do [mark the question as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this answered your questions :)